# Varying fonts of some html elements on dektop mode for different mobile and different browsers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser, viewport-units

I have set a fixed font-size for the "p" and "h4" elements in my footer but I keep experiencing different font-size while using desktop mode on my mobile. I get the expected result while using firefox, and safari but a weird result while using chrome.

Here is the reference website, [link to the website](https://travelaja.vercel.app/).

Attached below are images to visually illustrate the issue.

[image]

[image]

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container-item details">
     <h2>travelaja</h2>
      <p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisisleo, vel.
      </p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container-item contact">
   <h3>Contact</h3>
   <h4>Address: Jl.Codelaras No.205A Kediri, Pare AG17</h4>
   ...
</div>
```

and this is the CSS I use to style it.

```
footer .container .container-item p.content {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

footer .container .contact h4 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

I reduced the fonts to 1.0rem but it was not looking good on safari and then it was quite normal in chrome.

I also ensured that I have this meta tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: I don't seem to have this issue on your site

Comment: What browser are you using? And are you using it in desktop mode? @ninadepina

Comment: I've tried on Firefox, chrome and safari

Comment: @ninadepina and they all display properly? If then, maybe I should not worry about it anymore.

Comment: Yeah everything looks fine, also when I resize :)

Comment: @ninadepina wow, that's weird. Thanks for the helping to check.